# Xpath. How do I get tag name given Selector. Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, selector

I have this xpath that returns a list of selectors.

```
for i in response.xpath('//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]'):
     print i
```

results:

```
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3 class="fusion-header-tagline"><img s'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3 class="features-title role-element l'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h2 style="text-align: center;">Sell you'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<p>We buy properties in any shape, any p'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<p>Attempting to sell your house in Marl'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span st'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<p><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1439'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3><span style="color: #000000;">No com'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3><span style="color: #000000;">You do'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3><span style="color: #000000;">We wil'>
<Selector xpath='//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]' data=u'<h3><span style="color: #000000;">No lis'>
```

How do I get tag name for each selector? I.e.  `h3, h3, h2, p, p, h2` etc.
I tried

```
print name(i)
print i.name()
```

That doesn't work.
How do I use `xpath name()` properly to get the tag name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
for i in response.xpath('//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]'):
    print i.xpath('name()')
```

This will select the `name()` from each element selected on the first xpath

Comment: thanks. but i need to work with the node to further extract text from it. Which , i assume, will be impossible in this case. And still your solution returns Value error - ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]/name()

Comment: @BillyJhon in this case, I edited my answer. You can use xpath from the element you are to get the `name()` property, and then keep using the element for other purposes

Comment: getting value error XPath error: Invalid expression in ./name()

Comment: @BillyJhon sorry, there was an error. Remove the `./` and it will work. I have tested it with the new code and it works.

Comment: Same `Invalid expression` error, as Lucas mentioned, you need to remove the `./` prefix, but because it's part of the XPath expression, I solved it doing this: `response.xpath('//EXPRESSION/*').xpath('name()').get()`

Answer (score 2):

Selectors in Scrapy do not actually represent nodes from the HTML tree but have to be seen as the abstraction of referring to the result of a XPath or CSS selector. Hence, they also have no notion of tag names or attributes. But you can use the `root` attribute to easily access the underlying root node of a selector:

```
for i in response.xpath('//*[name()="h2" or name()="h3" or name()="p"]'):
     print(i.root.tag)
```

Comment: I have tried selector.root.tag an got an error 'str' object has no attribute 'tag' Is there other way to get the tag name of selector